# In Notepad ++ 7.3.1 is there a way to display a long list as two columns automatically?

Tags: notepad++, formatting, editing

For example,

Item 1  Item 45
Item 2  Item 46
Item 3  Item 47
...     ...
Item 44 Item 88

Etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this in Notepad++. Notepad++ is primarily a plaintext file editor, so it is not designed for fancy formatting of text (like Word or other "print media" tools).